# typedef map, debug assertion on for loop, map/set incompatible

Tags: c++, debugging, iterator, stdmap, assertion

So I was coding when I run into a Debug assertion. 
Now I am very interessted why this piece of code does not work:

```
for(Model::MeshMap::iterator it = obj1->GetMeshes().begin(); it != obj1->GetMeshes().end(); it++)
```

and this piece of code does:

```
Model::MeshMap obj1meshes = obj1->GetMeshes();
for(Model::MeshMap::iterator it = obj1meshes.begin(); it != obj1meshes.end(); it++)
```

In the model class I have this:

```
typedef std::map<std::string, Mesh*> MeshMap;
```

Comment: What returns `GetMeshes`? copy, or reference?

Comment: @ForEveR: The beauty here is that whatever the answer, it means that both versions are horribly broken...

Comment: What does the debug assert say? And does it really happen on the for line, or in something in the loop?

Comment: @ForEveR: GetMeshes returns the map I wanted to use. MeshMap GetMeshes() {return m_Meshes;} m_Meshes = of type Meshmap.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like `GetMeshes` returns copy and you are trying to compare `iterator` of one container with `iterator` of another container. Such comparison is not valid in terms of checked iterators in MSVC. And, thanks to @Mike Seymour, this comparison is not valid according to the C++ standard.

Comment: More importantly, such a comparison is not valid according to the C++ standard.

Comment: Aha so this creates a copy of the mesh map? Which is solved by using the reference. Thanks!